# Nested enumerate with multicols

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol, enumitem

I am currently working with nested `enumerate` environments in which the second level is typeset using a `multicols`, as follows :

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{multicols}{5}
          \raggedcolumns
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item $0$
            \item $0$
            \item $-1$
            \item $-\infty $
            \item $\infty $
            \item $1$
            \item $2$
            \item $2$
            \item $1$
            \item $1$
            \item $2$
            \item $1$
            \item $0$
            \item $\textcolor {red}\nexists $
            \item $1$
            \item $\textcolor {red}\nexists $
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Although the columns are created properly, the last column remains empty. Frank's balancing algorithm seems to provide a 4+4+4+4+0 balancing solution for this five (5) column layout. I would like the layout to use all five columns, given that there are more than a total of five items.

My questions are:

1. Is this really due to `multicols`' balancing algorithm, or is it something specific in  or missing from my code?
2. **Main question** : is there a way to balance the layout using ALL available columns, for example 4+3+3+3+3, **that does not require the use of `\columnbreak`**?
3. I tried using `\usepackage[balancingshow]{multicol}` to see what was happening with the balancing algorithm, but the tracing output is only showing badness for columns 1-4. Is this normal?

Note that if you comment the last `\item`, the balancing solution is 3+3+3+3+3, which uses all five (5) columns.

My motivation for wanting this is that I'm creating a very personalized *question/answer*-type package for my colleagues and the answers should be typeset using the "least possible amount of space". The presentation does not seem very optimal/natural when the last column remains empty.

I am aware that `multicols`' balancing algorithm cannot be optimal for all given situations and that it does a very good job in most cases, along with the fact that the package was created to typeset text.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the`shortlst` package and a small patch in order to be able to choose the number of columns. It requires using shortlst, of course, `setspace` to adjust interlining and `xkeyval`. As shortlst  in not in TeXLive nor MiKTeX (due to problems with its license, as far I know), you'll have to download from CTAN and install it in your local texmf directory.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{shortlst,setspace,xkeyval}%
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[5]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 5 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![enter image description here][1]
\newenvironment{shortanswers}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\ensuremath{(\alph{enumi})}}
`\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item%
      \begin{shortanswers}
        \item $ 0 $
        \item $ 0 $
        \item $ -1 $
        \item $-\infty $
        \item $\infty $
        \item $1$
        \item $2$
        \item $2$
        \item $1$
        \item $1$
        \item $2$
        \item $1$
        \item $0$
        \item $\textcolor {red}\nexists $
        \item $1$
        \item $\textcolor {red}\nexists $
      \end{shortanswers}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution! I've used `shortlst` before, but I ended up switching to a combination of `enumitem` and `multicols` for two reasons: **1.** I found shortlst not to be easily customizable with regards to spacing, columns, etc. I see you've countered this by "patching" its functionalities, which brings me to the second point. **2.** For the moment, I'm not sure the use of `shortlst` is a good choice on the long run, especially given that my entire team is using MiKTeK. I'd much prefer using "standard" packages that won't disappear or require "patches/hacks" every now and then.

Comment: @feculededentier: For me the main point is that it works as I want. It's the only package, along with `tablists`(version 0.0e!) that has these functionalities: putting items in columns while retaining a simple list-like synta. Multienum can do a similar formatting, but with a tabular-like syntax. And it 's the only one that uses 2 (or more) columns for an item _automatically_. Unfortunately I am not sufficiently aware of the internals of (La)TeX to make a valuable successor to this package that would incorporate my patches…

Answer (score 2):

*edited (2017): no more use of `xintfrac` as computations can be done with `\numexpr`. Only need to load `xinttools`.*

---

My two cents guess about the situation creating this stress to `multicol` is that it arises when you want `D` columns, have `N` items (which will occupy the same vertical space, imagine short words to simplify), when `N\leq ceil(N/D)*(D-1)`.

For example `N=16`, `D=5` gives `4*4=16`. Bad. `D=7` gives `3*6=18`. Bad. `D=4` gives `4*3=12` good, `D=6` gives `3*5=15` good, `D=3` gives `6*2=12` good.

```
\input xinttools.sty % \xintApply, \xintListWithSep, \»intSeq
\def\GoodDivisions #1{For #1: 
    \xintListWithSep{, }{\xintApply{\TestGoodness {#1}}{\xintSeq {1}{#1}}}}

\def\Ceil #1#2{\numexpr(#1+#2/2-1)/#2\relax}

\catcode`@ 11
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\def\TestGoodness #1#2{#2 is
                       \ifnum #1>\numexpr\Ceil{#1}{#2}*(#2-1)\relax
                       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
                       \else
                       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
                       \fi
                       {Good}{Bad}}
\catcode`@ 12

\GoodDivisions {16}

\GoodDivisions {20}

\GoodDivisions {32}

\GoodDivisions {23}

\nopagenumbers

\bye
```

These predictions are untested! (works for `16` and `20` items at least.

[image: gooddivisions]

Here is now a table giving for each number of items up to `60` the compatible choices for a multicol with `D`  columns.

[image: table of good divisions]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vscale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand*\TestColumns[1]{%
  \xintListWithSep{&}{\xintApply{\TestGoodness {#1}}{123456789{10}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\TestGoodness[2]{%
  \ifnum #1>\numexpr\Ceil{#1}{#2}*(#2-1)\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi G{\textcolor{red}{B}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\Ceil[2]{\numexpr(#1+#2/2-1)/#2\relax}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tabular}{c*{10}c}
  &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
\hline
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{60}}
            \do {#1&\TestColumns {#1}\\}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: my predictions for `20` items seem validated! the `9` columns case is interesting, `multicol` does then only `7` columns, `20=6x3+2`.

Comment: so far everything I have tested (`N=16`, `N=19`, `N=20`, `N=48`, `N=49` etc..) is compatible with the predictions from the table...

Comment: Interesting analysis!

I'd be intrigued to know whether this analysis is accurate, because it implies that the solution in which _every column has the same amount of equally sized elements, except for the first column which contains an extra element_ is always bad. Even for displaying text, I don't see how this output is "bad" or undesirable.

Comment: @feculededentier the first case is with `4` lines we want to have over `3` columns:`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  first line\newline
  second line\newline
  third line\newline
  fourth line
\end{multicols}
\end{document}`  `multicol` understandably excludes doing `1+1+2` but does not seem to consider making `2+1+1`, and ends up doing `2+2`, thus leaving an empty third column.

Comment: @feculededentier from the table above using `3` columns is safe if the text ends up on at least `5` lines, and using `4` columns is safe for text ending up on at least `10` lines, and using `5` columns for text ending up on at least `17` lines. Naturally, regular text might have enough stretch to move a word to an additional line and thus the stress on multicols is more easily seen when doing things like in your post, with one-liners, rather than full paragraphs allowing reflowing of text.